How to hide specific fields from WooCommerce Admin Products Quick Edit
I'm trying to hide some WooCommerce fields from the "Quick Edit" window: "Date", "Tax status", "Tax class", "Weight", "L/W/H", "Shipping class", "Backorders?" and "Enable reviews" fields.
These are the fields I'll want to hide from the "Quick Edit" window:

I have tried to add a "display: none;" property, but I can't figure out to which elements to apply it and how to apply it, since I would like to hide only the fields in red.
I'm using WooCommerce v9.1.2

Updated
You can use CSS :has() pseudo-class to selects elements that contain other elements.
Then we use display:none !important to hide those elements.
Try the following that will hide specific fields in Product Quick Edit:
// CSS
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_quick_edit_start',  'hide_specific_product_quick_edit_fields_css' );
function hide_specific_product_quick_edit_fields_css() {
    // Hide weight, dimensions, backorder, Password, Tax status, Tax class, Shipping class and Enable reviews fields
    ?><style>
    .inline-edit-date, .dimension_fields, .backorder_field, 
    div:has(> label > span > input.inline-edit-password-input),
    label:has(> span > select[name=_tax_status]), 
    label:has(> span > select[name=_tax_class]),
    div:has(> span > select[name=_shipping_class]), 
    div:has(> label > input[name=comment_status]) {display:none !important;}
    </style><?php 
}

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and work.

Awesome, right to the point! I tried to hide also the date with $('.inline-edit-date').closest('div').hide(); but failed, can you please help me? @LoicTheAxtec

I have updated my answer code using pure CSS rules instead of a mix of CSS and jQuery...

Is there a way to do it whitout having spaces where the fields have been hidden? @LoicTheAztec

@Xim Not really, as this is about some hard-coded <br> tags in between fields that is not possible to target.
